# How do you separate two nav elements from one another in css and html?

Tags: html, css

I have two nav elements that I'm using one just below the header and another one where I have the nav element nested inside an aside element. I added the code for the HTML for the nav elements and added the code for the CSS for the nav elements at the bottom of the page. I also have a picture of the website that you guys can look at which is also at the bottom of the page. What I am trying to do is add a horizontal navigation bar for one nav element and a vertical navigation bar for another nav element, but the first nav element I created is overriding the CSS for my second nav element. I'm trying to figure out a way to separate the two so the second nav element has its own CSS code. I don't know if I can use a class attribute or id attribute for the second nav element so it's separate from the first nav element I created. I can really use some help in figuring out this issue.

Here is the HTML code for the first nav element:

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class="current" href="index7.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Product List</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Personal</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Decoration Ideas</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Outdoor</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Indoor</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Table</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Treats</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Join Email</a>       
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<aside>
  <nav id="nav_list">    
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="props.html">Props</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="costumes.html">Costumes</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="effects.html">Special Effects</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="masks.html">Masks</a>
      </li>
    </ul> 
  </nav>
</aside>
```

Here is the CSS code for the first and second nav elements

```css
/* nav styles */
nav {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0px !important;
  left: 0px !important;
  display: block !important;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul > li {
    float: left;
}
nav a {
    display: block;
    width: 160px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.current {
    color: orange
}
.submenu {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 3em;
}
.submenu li {
    float: none; 
}
.submenu a:hover {
    background-color: gray;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
} 

/* second nav element */
aside {
  position: absolute !important;  
  top: 100px !important;
  left: 0px !important;
  display: block !important;
}

#nav_list ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  <!-- margin-left: 1.25em; -->
  margin-bottom; 1.5em;
}
#nav_list ul li {
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  <!-- border: 2px solid blue; --> 
}

#nav_list a:hover {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Website screenshot below:

[image: website right here]

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is targeting all nav elements because you asked it to. You have no specific nav or ul classes (or id's) assigned.

I would suggest you give each nav element different classes (or Id's) so you can then target each one separately in your CSS and apply your desired styling. For example you can give the horizontal nav a class="horizontal-nav" and the vertical nav a class="vertical-nav".

That way, one is separate from the other style-wise.

Comment: Yeah. I think that's better. He can target the nav nested in the aside

Answer (score 0):

check out the !important stuff.

```
   <style>
    /* nav styles */
    nav {
      position: absolute !important;
      top: 0px !important;
      left: 0px !important;
      display: block !important;
    }

    nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
    }
    nav ul > li {
        float: left;
    }
    nav a {
        display: block;
        width: 160px;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 1em;
        padding-bottom: 1em;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #000000;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .current {
        color: orange
    }
    .submenu {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        top: 3em;
    }
    .submenu li {
        float: none; 
    }
    .submenu a:hover {
        background-color: gray;
    }
    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    } 

    /* second nav element */
    aside {
      position: absolute !important;  
      top: 100px !important;
      left: 0px !important;
      display: block !important;
    }

    #nav_list ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      <!-- margin-left: 1.25em; -->
      margin-bottom; 1.5em;
    }
    #nav_list ul li {
      width: 200px;
      margin-bottom: .5em;
      <!-- border: 2px solid blue; --> 
    }

    #nav_list a:hover {
        background-color: gray;
    }

    </style>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="current" href="index7.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Product List</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Personal</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Decoration Ideas</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Outdoor</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Indoor</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Table</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Treats</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Join Email</a>       
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <aside>
      <nav id="nav_list">    
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="props.html">Props</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="costumes.html">Costumes</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="effects.html">Special Effects</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="masks.html">Masks</a>
          </li>
        </ul> 
      </nav>
    </aside>
```